# Can anyone identify this set for me? It's a mech with white, grey and gold elements

Tags: set-identification, ninjago

What LEGO set is this? I am trying to find its manual/instruction. [image]

Answer (score 3):

This is from Titan Mech Battle (70737). Identified by unique [tile with sticker](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=63864pb039#T=C&C=86). [Instructions](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions/70737) can be downloaded directly from LEGO Service.

[image]